# Ways Of Matrix Multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A \in F^{11 \times10}$ and $B\in$ $F^{10\times11}$

We only know $2$ rows of $A$ and $3$ columns of $B$.
How many entries of $B\cdot A$ can we know?

I think the answer is none, because there are dot product, row-row, column-column operations but no column-row one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The $(i,j)$th entry of $BA$ is the $i$th row of $B$ times the $j$th column of $A$.  Because we don't know any of the rows of $B$ completely (and we don't know any of the columns of $A$ completely), we don't know any of the entries of $BA$.

Answer (score 7):

Hint: This is a picture of matrix multiplication
[image]

Comment: But the question is asking about $BA$, not $AB$.

Comment: @LittleO This picture shows also that matrix multiplication between $A$ and $B$ makes sense only if the number of element in a row of $A$ are the same as the number of element in the column of $B$, therefore if this property is not satisfied you can't multiply two matrices. :)

Comment: Well, your answer is a good hint because it shows how matrix multiplication works.